# Compiling ettercap 0.7.4.1 from source under Ubuntu 11.10 (linker error)

Tags: c, gcc, ubuntu, compiler-errors

I would like to compile ettercap 0.7.4.1 unter ubuntu 11.10 However, I just can't get it to compile. These are the steps I am executing:

```
$ ./autogen.sh
 ...
$ ./configure --enable-debug --enable-maintainer-mode --enable-gtk
 ...

$ make  
/bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CC   --mode=link gcc -g -ggdb -Wmissing-prototypes -Wno-uninitialized -Wformat-security -Wsign-compare -Wall -I/usr/include/pcap     -g -ggdb -Wmissing-prototypes -Wno-uninitialized -Wformat-security -Wsign-compare -Wall -I/usr/include/pcap     -export-dynamic -lresolv -lz -lpthread -lltdl -ldl -ldl  -lpcap -lnet -lssl -lcrypto -lpcre -lpanel -lmenu -lform -lncurses -pthread -lgtk-x11-2.0 -lgdk-x11-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lcairo -lfreetype -lfontconfig -lpango-1.0 -lgmodule-2.0 -latk-1.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lgthread-2.0 -lrt -lglib-2.0   -lgthread-2.0   -lresolv -lz -lpthread -lltdl -ldl -ldl  -lpcap -lnet -lssl -lcrypto -lpcre -lpanel -lmenu -lform -lncurses -pthread -lgtk-x11-2.0 -lgdk-x11-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lcairo -lfreetype -lfontconfig -lpango-1.0 -lgmodule-2.0 -latk-1.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lgthread-2.0 -lrt -lglib-2.0   -lgthread-2.0  -o ettercap ettercap-ec_capture.o ettercap-ec_checksum.o ettercap-ec_conf.o ettercap-ec_connbuf.o ettercap-ec_conntrack.o ettercap-ec_debug.o ettercap-ec_decode.o ettercap-ec_dispatcher.o ettercap-ec_dissect.o ettercap-ec_error.o ettercap-ec_file.o ettercap-ec_filter.o ettercap-ec_fingerprint.o ettercap-ec_format.o ettercap-ec_globals.o ettercap-ec_hash.o ettercap-ec_hook.o ettercap-ec_inet.o ettercap-ec_inject.o ettercap-ec_interfaces.o ettercap-ec_log.o ettercap-ec_main.o ettercap-ec_manuf.o ettercap-ec_mitm.o ettercap-ec_packet.o ettercap-ec_parser.o ettercap-ec_passive.o ettercap-ec_plugins.o ettercap-ec_poll.o ettercap-ec_profiles.o ettercap-ec_resolv.o ettercap-ec_scan.o ettercap-ec_send.o ettercap-ec_services.o ettercap-ec_session.o ettercap-ec_signals.o ettercap-ec_socket.o ettercap-ec_sniff.o ettercap-ec_sniff_bridge.o ettercap-ec_sniff_unified.o ettercap-ec_sslwrap.o ettercap-ec_stats.o ettercap-ec_streambuf.o ettercap-ec_strings.o ettercap-ec_threads.o ettercap-ec_ui.o ettercap-ec_update.o mitm/ettercap-ec_arp_poisoning.o mitm/ettercap-ec_dhcp_spoofing.o mitm/ettercap-ec_icmp_redirect.o mitm/ettercap-ec_port_stealing.o protocols/ettercap-ec_arp.o protocols/ettercap-ec_eth.o protocols/ettercap-ec_fddi.o protocols/ettercap-ec_cooked.o protocols/ettercap-ec_gre.o protocols/ettercap-ec_icmp.o protocols/ettercap-ec_ip.o protocols/ettercap-ec_ip6.o protocols/ettercap-ec_ppp.o protocols/ettercap-ec_prism.o protocols/ettercap-ec_rawip.o protocols/ettercap-ec_tcp.o protocols/ettercap-ec_tr.o protocols/ettercap-ec_vlan.o protocols/ettercap-ec_udp.o protocols/ettercap-ec_wifi.o dissectors/ettercap-ec_bgp.o dissectors/ettercap-ec_cvs.o dissectors/ettercap-ec_dhcp.o dissectors/ettercap-ec_dns.o dissectors/ettercap-ec_ftp.o dissectors/ettercap-ec_http.o dissectors/ettercap-ec_imap.o dissectors/ettercap-ec_icq.o dissectors/ettercap-ec_irc.o dissectors/ettercap-ec_ldap.o dissectors/ettercap-ec_mountd.o dissectors/ettercap-ec_msn.o dissectors/ettercap-ec_mysql.o dissectors/ettercap-ec_napster.o dissectors/ettercap-ec_nntp.o dissectors/ettercap-ec_ospf.o dissectors/ettercap-ec_pop.o dissectors/ettercap-ec_portmap.o dissectors/ettercap-ec_radius.o dissectors/ettercap-ec_rcon.o dissectors/ettercap-ec_rip.o dissectors/ettercap-ec_rlogin.o dissectors/ettercap-ec_smb.o dissectors/ettercap-ec_smtp.o dissectors/ettercap-ec_snmp.o dissectors/ettercap-ec_ssh.o dissectors/ettercap-ec_socks.o dissectors/ettercap-ec_telnet.o dissectors/ettercap-ec_vnc.o dissectors/ettercap-ec_vrrp.o dissectors/ettercap-ec_x11.o dissectors/ettercap-ec_ymsg.o ../src/missing/strlcpy.o ../src/missing/strlcat.o os/libec_os.a interfaces/daemon/libec_daemon.a interfaces/text/libec_text.a interfaces/curses/libec_curses.a  interfaces/gtk/libec_gtk.a -lresolv -lz -lpthread -lltdl -ldl -ldl 
libtool: link: gcc -g -ggdb -Wmissing-prototypes -Wno-uninitialized -Wformat-security -Wsign-compare -Wall -I/usr/include/pcap -g -ggdb -Wmissing-prototypes -Wno-uninitialized -Wformat-security -Wsign-compare -Wall -I/usr/include/pcap -pthread -pthread -o ettercap ettercap-ec_capture.o ettercap-ec_checksum.o ettercap-ec_conf.o ettercap-ec_connbuf.o ettercap-ec_conntrack.o ettercap-ec_debug.o ettercap-ec_decode.o ettercap-ec_dispatcher.o ettercap-ec_dissect.o ettercap-ec_error.o ettercap-ec_file.o ettercap-ec_filter.o ettercap-ec_fingerprint.o ettercap-ec_format.o ettercap-ec_globals.o ettercap-ec_hash.o ettercap-ec_hook.o ettercap-ec_inet.o ettercap-ec_inject.o ettercap-ec_interfaces.o ettercap-ec_log.o ettercap-ec_main.o ettercap-ec_manuf.o ettercap-ec_mitm.o ettercap-ec_packet.o ettercap-ec_parser.o ettercap-ec_passive.o ettercap-ec_plugins.o ettercap-ec_poll.o ettercap-ec_profiles.o ettercap-ec_resolv.o ettercap-ec_scan.o ettercap-ec_send.o ettercap-ec_services.o ettercap-ec_session.o ettercap-ec_signals.o ettercap-ec_socket.o ettercap-ec_sniff.o ettercap-ec_sniff_bridge.o ettercap-ec_sniff_unified.o ettercap-ec_sslwrap.o ettercap-ec_stats.o ettercap-ec_streambuf.o ettercap-ec_strings.o ettercap-ec_threads.o ettercap-ec_ui.o ettercap-ec_update.o mitm/ettercap-ec_arp_poisoning.o mitm/ettercap-ec_dhcp_spoofing.o mitm/ettercap-ec_icmp_redirect.o mitm/ettercap-ec_port_stealing.o protocols/ettercap-ec_arp.o protocols/ettercap-ec_eth.o protocols/ettercap-ec_fddi.o protocols/ettercap-ec_cooked.o protocols/ettercap-ec_gre.o protocols/ettercap-ec_icmp.o protocols/ettercap-ec_ip.o protocols/ettercap-ec_ip6.o protocols/ettercap-ec_ppp.o protocols/ettercap-ec_prism.o protocols/ettercap-ec_rawip.o protocols/ettercap-ec_tcp.o protocols/ettercap-ec_tr.o protocols/ettercap-ec_vlan.o protocols/ettercap-ec_udp.o protocols/ettercap-ec_wifi.o dissectors/ettercap-ec_bgp.o dissectors/ettercap-ec_cvs.o dissectors/ettercap-ec_dhcp.o dissectors/ettercap-ec_dns.o dissectors/ettercap-ec_ftp.o dissectors/ettercap-ec_http.o dissectors/ettercap-ec_imap.o dissectors/ettercap-ec_icq.o dissectors/ettercap-ec_irc.o dissectors/ettercap-ec_ldap.o dissectors/ettercap-ec_mountd.o dissectors/ettercap-ec_msn.o dissectors/ettercap-ec_mysql.o dissectors/ettercap-ec_napster.o dissectors/ettercap-ec_nntp.o dissectors/ettercap-ec_ospf.o dissectors/ettercap-ec_pop.o dissectors/ettercap-ec_portmap.o dissectors/ettercap-ec_radius.o dissectors/ettercap-ec_rcon.o dissectors/ettercap-ec_rip.o dissectors/ettercap-ec_rlogin.o dissectors/ettercap-ec_smb.o dissectors/ettercap-ec_smtp.o dissectors/ettercap-ec_snmp.o dissectors/ettercap-ec_ssh.o dissectors/ettercap-ec_socks.o dissectors/ettercap-ec_telnet.o dissectors/ettercap-ec_vnc.o dissectors/ettercap-ec_vrrp.o dissectors/ettercap-ec_x11.o dissectors/ettercap-ec_ymsg.o ../src/missing/strlcpy.o ../src/missing/strlcat.o -Wl,--export-dynamic  -lpcap /usr/lib/libnet.so -lssl -lcrypto -lpcre -lpanel -lmenu -lform -lncurses /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk-x11-2.0.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpangoft2-1.0.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpangocairo-1.0.so -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcairo.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so -lfontconfig /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpango-1.0.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmodule-2.0.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libatk-1.0.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so -lrt /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgthread-2.0.so os/libec_os.a interfaces/daemon/libec_daemon.a interfaces/text/libec_text.a interfaces/curses/libec_curses.a interfaces/gtk/libec_gtk.a -lresolv -lz -lpthread /usr/lib/libltdl.so -ldl -pthread
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so: undefined reference to symbol 'gdk_threads_enter'
/usr/bin/ld: note: 'gdk_threads_enter' is defined in DSO /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk-x11-2.0.so so try adding it to the linker command line
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk-x11-2.0.so: could not read symbols: Invalid operation
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [ettercap] Error 1
```

Does someone know how to resolve the linker error?

Solution: There seems to be a problem with the build script. This thread explains how to solve the issue:

http://forum.ubuntuusers.de/topic/ettercap-will-nicht/

(German ubuntu forum, but it the code listing are sufficient)

Comment: Are you using the developer package for libgdk?

Comment: ettercap 0.7.4.1 needs Gtk+ and Glib version >= 2.2.2 and if I am not wrong, I think urs is just Gtk 2.0 library. Cross check if you have all the libraries as said in the README and try building again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: There seems to be a problem with the build script. This thread explains how to solve the issue:

http://forum.ubuntuusers.de/topic/ettercap-will-nicht/

(German ubuntu forum, but it the code listing are sufficient)